# I need to fix a Null Pointer Eexception error. How do I do this?

Tags: nullpointerexception

Here's my code, two different classes. I'll divide the classes with ////////////
I'll display only the parts it's showing an error for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MadLibHelper
{
  Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
  MadLibsLibrary lib = new MadLibsLibrary();
  public void adjHelp()
  {
if (lib.adjective1.equals("?")){
  System.out.println("An adjective is a describing word. Ex. \"Beautiful\"");
  System.out.println("\nType an adjective: ");
  lib.adjective1 = user.nextLine();
}else{
  System.out.print(" ");
}
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MadLibsSchool
{
  private String storyborder = "ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo";
  MadLibsLibrary lib = new MadLibsLibrary();
  private int number1;
  Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in); //Creating a Scanner
  MadLibHelper help = new MadLibHelper(); //Creating a helper object
  public void setWords() //All nouns, adjectives, verbs, etc. are set
  {
    System.out.println("We will now select the words for your story!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Type an adjective: ");
    lib.adjective1 = user.nextLine();
help.adjHelp();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance of NullPointerException

at line if(lib.adjective1.equals("?"))
here lib.adjective1 may be NULL hence first check if lib.adjective1 != null && then do the operation.